# Differences in scoring from PMML model on different platforms

Tags: machine-learning, r, apache-hadoop, random-forest, predictive-modeling

I've built a toy Random Forest model in `R` (using the `German Credit` dataset from the `caret` package), exported it in `PMML 4.0` and deployed onto Hadoop, using the `Cascading Pattern` library.

I've run into an issue where `Cascading Pattern` scores the same data differently (in a binary classification problem) than the same model in `R`. Out of 200 observations, 2 are scored differently.

Why is this? Could it be due to a difference in the implementation of Random Forests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference was, it appears, due to the different implementation of Random Forests in `R` and `Cascading Pattern` (as well as `openscoring` which I tried later) with respect to ties in the tree voting - i.e. when an even number of trees are built (say, 500) and exactly half classify an application as `Good`, and the other half as `Bad`, the handling of those situations differs. Solved it by growing and odd (501) number of trees.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely explanation is that the two libraries do not quite support TreeModel in PMML in the same way. Perhaps one only supports a subset of features, and ignores ones it does not understand. This could cause different scoring.

I'd also double check that upstream parsing code is the same in both cases. Maybe a missing value is treated differently upstream.

Answer (score -1):

Decision Trees are unstable learners and very sensitive to changes in the input parameters.

Comment: Eh, but the model is fixed here and serialized as PMML. The question is about scoring from a given fixed model.